# pandas to_hdf function get Illegal instruction

Tags: python, macos, pandas, docker, hdf5

It seems an OS X 10.10 and docker specific error. When I try

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3], [2,3,4]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df.to_hdf(
    'test.h5', 
    'sites', 
    data_columns=True,
    format='t',
    complevel=5,
    complib='blosc'
)
```

I got error/message `Illegal instruction`. However, I tried the same code in OS X directly and the same docker container in CoreOS. They all works. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Please post your pandas version

Comment: My pandas version is 0.16.1. 
docker version is 1.6.2. 
pytables version is 3.2.0.

Comment: OK, well I don't own a m@c but this works fine on windows 7 using pandas 0.16.1 hopefully one of the pandas devs can help you out

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works with my mac too. Just not in a docker container.

Comment: I also tried my other ubuntu server with docker 1.6.2. It has the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I found the error only happens in pytable version 3.2.0. I fallback to version 3.1.1 and